# Kafka with Spark 2.1 Structured Streaming - cannot deserialize

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, deserialization, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

With Apache Spark version 2.1, I would like to use Kafka (0.10.0.2.5) as source for Structured Streaming with pyspark.

In the Kafka topic, I have json messages (pushed with Streamsets Data Collector).
However, I am not able to read it with following code:

```
kafka=spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:6667") \
.option("subscribe","mytopic").load()
msg=kafka.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
disp=msg.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```

It generates this error :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArrayDeserializer
```

I tried to add at the readStream line:

```
.option("value.serializer","org.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
.option("key.serializer","org.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
```

But it does not solve the problem.

Any idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this on `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer` for both key and value deserializer

Comment: take a help from here hope this is what you looking for `https://github.com/akashsethi24/Spark-Kafka-Stream-Example/blob/master/src/main/scala/KafkaConsumer.scala`

Comment: It tried but it does not help. Maybe because I am using Structured Streaming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I found the solution: I added the following jar in dependency:

spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10-2.1.0.jar

(after having downloaded it from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.10/2.1.0)

Comment: It works perfectly! 
`pyspark  --jars spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.2.jar,spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.3.2.jar`allows me to start my test.